# Pass Parameters Between Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application with a main window that loads in text file(s) and processes them.  Once the processing is done, it creates a list of network switch objects.  I can then perform various checks and queries on the data.  These checks or queries use child windows. I have been passing the list of switches - here's an example of a child window where I modified the constructor to take my list of switches.  I am wondering if this is a bad design or if there is a way to link the child window to the data in the list without having to pass it in.  The next major step in this project is going to be a GUI front-end to browse all the data I am parsing out, rather than just run reports.  So I want to learn to do it the right way now.

```
 public partial class LogFileWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<LogFileEntry> _LogFileCollection = new ObservableCollection<LogFileEntry>();

    private List<CiscoSwitch> SwitchList = new List<CiscoSwitch>();

     // constructor modified to accept a list as a paramter
    public LogFileWindow(List<CiscoSwitch> sl)
    {
        SwitchList = sl;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

.....
}

Comment: Yeah... MVVM type design is all well and good until you need to communicate between logically separated pieces of your UI.  I had to do this once and it's a bit of a pain.  I went with a broadcast event type mechanism using the `EventAggregator`.

Comment: @EdS. Why don't you think, that MVVM is the right model for inter-GUI communication tasks? I personally think, that EventAggregator is a little bit over-engineered...

Comment: @MarioFraiß: I never said that, I think it is a step up.  I also think it makes some problems that used to be simple more difficult, but there are always tradeoffs.  In separating UI components you make it difficult to communicate between them, and while perhaps suboptimal, in the real world you often need such communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look at the wpf MVVM model, like Kent already mentioned. A very good starting point is this post on MSDN:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/wpf/thread/b8922be3-e73c-4d90-9bc6-172421fb6b1c

Greetings,

Comment: thanks.  a lot to learn, but it looks like that is what I want.

Comment: hi, I'm glad that i could help you.